# Some questions about sowing/growing timothy grass (in pot / indoor)

Tags: indoors, grass, sowing

I'm going to sow and grow timothy grass (*Phleum pratense*) in a pot (in a lab)  with a controlled environment (to make some scientific measurement).

But I know nothing about growing plants.

So, my questions are:

1. How much seed do I need for an pot for timothy grass? (my estimation is `14cm` x `40cm` pot =  `0.2g` seed). Is it too much?
2. At my `home depot` (technicaly `dcm homac` in japan) There is an soil for sowing. Generally speaking, Do these types of soil only for sowing the seed (and later change the soil)?, or just leave plant in this soil as it is?
3. What is good temperture for timothy? and how much should I water it?.
4. Since I'm sowing in controlled temperature/light, Sowing in late November would be and issue right? (Or does seed somehow know what time of the year is it? haha. `Please, I have no idea`)

If there any other things to consider, please let me know. Thank you

Comment: After the grass germinates, how long do you want to keep it alive in the pot? If less than 12 weeks, you can sprout and grow the seeds in the same container. Also, what fertilizer are you going to use? If keeping the grass for less than 12 weeks, than a water soluble one will be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think the duration will little less than 12 weeks. About the fertilizer I've not sure. Do you have suggestions?